# How to make a height auto wrapper expand depending on the logo's height

Tags: html, css, height, expand

I'm having an issue where I want to make the height of a wrapper expand depending on the logo's height. I know there is a lot of questions in Google like this, but none of them actually worked for me.

I've tried the height: auto !important method.

I've also tried min-height and it works in most cases, **but it doesn't work for me when I have the height as auto.**

Here's my CSS:

```
.header {  
width: 100%; 
height: auto;
min-height: 80px; 
position: relative;
background: red; }

.logo { float: left; border: 0; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
  <img src="logo.png" class="logo"/>
  <br class="clear" />
</div>
```

Please note I tried it without the float as well. I apologize in advance if this question is an easy fix. I did my research and none of them worked out for me or anyone I found was in my situation anyway. I would appreciate some help. Thank you !

Comment: Have you styled the .clear class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your logo is float:left, you need to use so-called clearfix, all manipulations with hight or min-height are wrong way. There are many kinds of clearfix. Since you have `<br class="clear" />`, you just need to add `.clear { clear: both; }` to your stylesheet, but this is not the best method. Here is better one:

CSS:

```
.header {  
    width: 100%; 
    background: red; 
}

.logo { 
    float: left;
}

.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

HTML:

```
<div class="header clearfix">
  <img src="logo.png" class="logo" />
</div>
```

You can see working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZCXVr/1/
P.S. giving the header `overflow: hidden` is also a method, but i don't reccomend to use it

Comment: The problem happens when a floated element is within a container box, that element does not automatically force the container’s height adjust to the floated element. When an element is floated, its parent no longer contains it because the float is removed from the flow.

Comment: add <div class="clearfix"></div>
as describe by Serge it should fix your issue.

OR you can use jQuery height api for this.

Answer (score 2):

try giving the header `overflow: hidden`